# website with fluctuating traffic

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I have a web application that has very fluctuating traffic. I'm talking about 30 to 40 users daily to thousands of people simultaneously. It's a ticketing app so this kind of behavior is here to stay so I want to make a strategic choice I don't want to by a host with a high configuration because it's just going to be sitting around for most of the time. We're running a Node.js server so we usually run low on RAM. My question is this: what are my options and how difficult is it to go from a normal VPS to something like Microsoft Azure, Google Cloud, or AWS.

Comment: If folks are interested in creating a venue for these types of questions, follow the proposal for a [dedicated Cloud Computing site on StackExchange](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110490/cloud-computing-aws-azure-google-openstack-etc?referrer=Gtut7wQSWPk88jFJz_zqMg2) and up-vote some sample questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to be specific without knowing more about your application architecture but both AWS Lambda and Google App Engine offer 'serverless architecture' and support Node.js. Serverless architectures allow you to host code directly rather than running servers and associated infrastructure.  Scaling is given to you by the services, costs are based on consumption and you can configure constraints and alerts to prevent racking up huge unexpected bills.  In both instances you would need to front the services with additional Google or AWS services to make them accessible to customers, but these offer a great way to scale and pay only for what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So you're suggesting I go with a pay as you go option. I have never heard of serverless architecture. Is that going to involves me making changes to my actual code in order to deploy it ?

Comment: To some degree you'll have to change your code deployment, but most of your code can probably stay very similar. You'll have to configure the API Gateway (which will take the place of whatever you have on node handling routing to functions) and then turn each of those functions into a lambda function on AWS. Then hook them up. Job done, and it should scale up/down seamlessly. Each lambda has its own cpu and memory for the tiny amount of time its running so that aspect of resource allocation goes away. Try and minimize memory usage and runtime per function as this is the basic for billing.

Answer (score 0):

A first step is to offload static content to Amazon S3 (or similar service). Those services will handle any load and will lessen the load on your web server.

If the load goes up/down gradually (eg over the course of 30 minutes), you can use Auto Scaling to add/remove Amazon EC2 servers based upon load metrics. For example, you probably don't need many servers at night.

However, for handling of spiky traffic, rewriting an application as Serverless will make it highly resilient, highly scalable and most likely a lot cheaper too!